# Multicol, strange page break

Tags: multicol

I want to understand why LaTeX gives some strange page breaks in multicol elements. Here is the code (also available at [https://www.sis.uta.fi/~jm58660/kirja.mwe.tex](https://www.sis.uta.fi/%7Ejm58660/kirja.mwe.tex)).

```
\documentclass[b5paper, finnish, 11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{Zallman}
\usepackage[bottom=0.9in,top=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount} % Kappaleiden välin asetus
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}          % Kappaleen alun sisennys   (0pt,  ts. ei sisennystä)
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{15pt}  % Helpotetaan tavutusta sallimalla pidemmät sanavälit
% \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
cumulative sum chart
\lettrine[lines=3]{D}
\newline \newline \newline \newline \newline
\textbf{\textit{D}-optimaalisuus} $D$-optimality\newline
\textbf{\textit{d}-separaatio} $d$-separation\newline
\textbf{Dantzig-valitsin} Dantzig selector\newline
\textbf{data} data\newline
\textbf{data-analyysi} data analysis\newline
\textbf{datajoukko} data set\newline
\textbf{datakehikko} data frame\newline
\textbf{datakuutio} data cube\newline
\textbf{datamatriisi} data matrix\newline
\textbf{datan esikäsittely} data pre\-processing\newline
\textbf{datan linkittäminen} data linkage\newline
\textbf{datan ruoppaus} data dredging\newline
\textbf{datan syvyys} data depth\newline
\textbf{datan tiivistäminen} data reduction\newline
\textbf{datan kurkistelu} data peeking\newline
\textbf{datanlouhinta} data mining\newline
\textbf{datan myrkyttäminen} data poisoning\newline
\textbf{datatiede} data science\newline
\textbf{datavetoinen} data driven\newline
\textbf{de facto -väestö} de facto population\newline
\textbf{de jure -väestö} de jure population\newline
\textbf{deflaatio} deflation\newline
\textbf{degeneroitunut jakauma} degenerate distribution\newline
\textbf{dekomponointi} decomposition$_1$\newline
\textbf{dekomponoituva malli} decomposable model\newline
\textbf{dekonvoluutio} deconvolution\newline
\textbf{deltamenetelmä} delta method\newline
\textbf{demografia} demography\newline
\textbf{derivaatta} derivative$_1$\newline
\textbf{derivoituvuus} differentiability\newline
\textbf{desiili} decile\newline
\textbf{determinaatiokerroin} coefficient of determination\newline
\textbf{determinantti} determinant\newline
\textbf{deterministinen} deterministic\newline
\textbf{devianssi} deviance\newline
\textbf{devianssi-informaatiokriteeri} deviance information criterion\newline
\textbf{devianssijäännös} deviance residual\newline
\textbf{diagnostiikka} diagnostics\newline
\textbf{diagnostinen suure} diagnostic sta\-tis\-tic\newline
\textbf{diagnostinen testi} diagnostic test\newline
\textbf{diagonaalimatriisi} diagonal matrix\newline
\textbf{diagrammi} diagram\newline
\textbf{differenssiyhtälö} difference equa\-tion\newline
\textbf{differensointi} differencing\newline
\textbf{differentiaaliyhtälö} differential equa\-tion\newline
\textbf{differentioituvuus} differentiability\newline
\textbf{differointi} differencing\newline
\textbf{diffuusi priori} diffuse prior\newline
\textbf{diffuusioindeksi} diffusion index\newline
\textbf{diffuusioprosessi} diffusion process\newline
\textbf{digammafunktio} digamma function\newline
\textbf{dikotomia} dichotomy\newline
\textbf{dikotominen muuttuja} dichotomous variable, binary variable\newline
\textbf{dimensiokirous} curse of dimensionality\newline
\textbf{dimension pienennys} dimension reduction\newline
\textbf{Diracin deltafunktio} Dirac's delta function\newline
\textbf{Diracin mitta} Dirac measure\newline
\textbf{Dirichlet-jakauma} Dirichlet distribution\newline
\textbf{Dirichlet-prosessi} Dirichlet process\newline
\textbf{diskonttaus} discounting\newline
\textbf{diskordanssi} discordance\newline
\textbf{diskordantit parit} discordant pairs\newline
\textbf{diskreetti} discrete\newline
\textbf{diskreetti jakauma} discrete distribution\newline
\textbf{diskreetti muuttuja} discrete variable\newline
\textbf{diskreettiaikainen} discrete-time\newline
\textbf{diskriminantti} discriminant\newline
\textbf{divergenssi} divergence$_1$\newline
\textbf{diversiteetti-indeksi} index of diversity\newline
\textbf{do-laskenta} do-calculus\newline
\textbf{do-operaattori} do-operator\newline
\textbf{duaalilause} dual theorem\newline
\textbf{duaalisuus} duality\newline
\textbf{dynaaminen kiintiöinti} dynamic treatment allocation\newline
\textbf{dynaaminen ohjelmointi} dynamic programming, dynamic optimization\newline
\textbf{dynaaminen optimointi} dynamic optimization\newline
\textbf{dynaaminen populaatio} dynamic population, open population
\lettrine[lines=3]{E}
\newline \newline \newline \newline \newline
\textbf{\textit{E}-optimaalisuus} $E$-optimality\newline
%% \textbf{ECM-algoritmi} ECM-algo\-rithm\newline
%% \textbf{ECME-algoritmi} ECME-algo\-rithm\newline
\textbf{editointisääntö} edit rule\newline
\textbf{edustava otos} representative sample\newline
\textbf{edustavuus} representativeness\newline
\textbf{ehdokasjakauma} candidate distribution, proposal distribution\newline
\textbf{ehdollinen autoregressio} conditional autoregression\newline
\textbf{ehdollinen jakauma} conditional distribution\newline
\textbf{ehdollinen odotusarvo} conditional expectation\newline
\textbf{ehdollinen riippumattomuus} con\-ditional independence\newline
\textbf{ehdollinen tiheysfunktio} conditional density function\newline
\textbf{ehdollinen todennäköisyys} conditional probability\newline
\textbf{ehdollinen uskottavuus} conditional likelihood\newline
\textbf{ehdollinen varianssi} conditional variance\newline
\textbf{ehdollistettu sirontakuvio} conditioning plot, coplot\newline
\textbf{ehdotusjakauma} proposal distribution, candidate distribution\newline
\textbf{ehkäisykoe} prevention trial\newline
\textbf{ei-merkitsevä} nonsignificant\newline
\textbf{ei-negatiivisesti definiitti} nonnegative definite\newline
\textbf{ei-normaalinen} non-normal\newline
\textbf{ei-satunnaisesti puuttuva} missing not at random\newline
\textbf{ekologinen harha} ecological fallacy, ecological bias\newline
\textbf{ekologinen korrelaatio} ecological correlation\newline
\textbf{ekologinen tutkimus} ecological study, aggregate-level study\newline
\textbf{ekologinen virhepäätelmä} ecological fallacy\newline
\textbf{ekonometria} econometrics\newline
\textbf{ekonometrikko} econometrician\newline
\textbf{eksakti testi} exact test\newline
\textbf{eksogeeninen muuttuja} exogenous variable\newline
\textbf{eksogeenisuus} exogeneity\newline
\textbf{eksponentiaalinen kasvu} exponential growth\newline
\textbf{eksponentiaalinen trendi} exponential trend\newline
\textbf{eksponenttijakauma} exponential distribution\newline
\textbf{eksponenttikäyrä} exponential curve\newline
\textbf{eksponenttinen kasvu} exponential growth\newline
\textbf{eksponenttinen silotus} exponential smoothing\newline
\textbf{eksponenttinen tasoitus} exponential smoothing\newline
\textbf{eksponenttinen trendi} exponential trend\newline
\textbf{eksponenttiperhe} exponential family\newline

\end{multicols}

\clearpage
\newpage

\end{document}
```

At the end of page 1 there is "Dirichlet-prosessi Dirichlet", and page 2 starts with "process". But there is a room for the line containing "process" at page 1. Then the left column at page two could end with "ehdollinen jakauma conditional distribution" and so on, so I see no reason for the page break.

Comment: Please post a MWE here. Links to external files are discouraged because your question might become meaningless if/when the link disappears (next week, or next year, or... ).

Comment: @campa, as you wish. (The link is valid for 3 months.)

Comment: 3 months is not very long:  the question is archived _forever_.

Comment: LaTeX does warn you about bad output `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 113--154`  note 10000 is the _maximum_ level of badness,  You are forcing this with the `\newline` commands. Never use repeated `\newline` (or `\\ `) nor use them at the end of a paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you are using lettrine for the big letters as there is no cut-in here into the pararaph text.

You were setting each letter list as a single paragraph, which causes several strange effects, and repeated `\newline` do not make a vertical space they make spurious lines of the paragraph that have no text so are underfull (and not dropped at a page break)

I changed all the `\newline` to a blank line, and left it the `\letterine` use although it appears wrong.

```
\documentclass[b5paper, finnish, 11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{Zallman}
\usepackage[bottom=0.9in,top=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount} % Kappaleiden välin asetus
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}          % Kappaleen alun sisennys   (0pt,  ts. ei sisennystä)
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{15pt}  % Helpotetaan tavutusta sallimalla pidemmät sanavälit
% \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
cumulative sum chart

\lettrine[lines=3]{D}{}
% why use lettrine here???????????
\mbox{}\\\mbox{}\\\mbox{}


\medskip

 

 

 


\textbf{\textit{D}-optimaalisuus} $D$-optimality


\textbf{\textit{d}-separaatio} $d$-separation


\textbf{Dantzig-valitsin} Dantzig selector


\textbf{data} data


\textbf{data-analyysi} data analysis


\textbf{datajoukko} data set


\textbf{datakehikko} data frame


\textbf{datakuutio} data cube


\textbf{datamatriisi} data matrix


\textbf{datan esikäsittely} data pre\-processing


\textbf{datan linkittäminen} data linkage


\textbf{datan ruoppaus} data dredging


\textbf{datan syvyys} data depth


\textbf{datan tiivistäminen} data reduction


\textbf{datan kurkistelu} data peeking


\textbf{datanlouhinta} data mining


\textbf{datan myrkyttäminen} data poisoning


\textbf{datatiede} data science


\textbf{datavetoinen} data driven


\textbf{de facto -väestö} de facto population


\textbf{de jure -väestö} de jure population


\textbf{deflaatio} deflation


\textbf{degeneroitunut jakauma} degenerate distribution


\textbf{dekomponointi} decomposition$_1$


\textbf{dekomponoituva malli} decomposable model


\textbf{dekonvoluutio} deconvolution


\textbf{deltamenetelmä} delta method


\textbf{demografia} demography


\textbf{derivaatta} derivative$_1$


\textbf{derivoituvuus} differentiability


\textbf{desiili} decile


\textbf{determinaatiokerroin} coefficient of determination


\textbf{determinantti} determinant


\textbf{deterministinen} deterministic


\textbf{devianssi} deviance


\textbf{devianssi-informaatiokriteeri} deviance information criterion


\textbf{devianssijäännös} deviance residual


\textbf{diagnostiikka} diagnostics


\textbf{diagnostinen suure} diagnostic sta\-tis\-tic


\textbf{diagnostinen testi} diagnostic test


\textbf{diagonaalimatriisi} diagonal matrix


\textbf{diagrammi} diagram


\textbf{differenssiyhtälö} difference equa\-tion


\textbf{differensointi} differencing


\textbf{differentiaaliyhtälö} differential equa\-tion


\textbf{differentioituvuus} differentiability


\textbf{differointi} differencing


\textbf{diffuusi priori} diffuse prior


\textbf{diffuusioindeksi} diffusion index


\textbf{diffuusioprosessi} diffusion process


\textbf{digammafunktio} digamma function


\textbf{dikotomia} dichotomy


\textbf{dikotominen muuttuja} dichotomous variable, binary variable


\textbf{dimensiokirous} curse of dimensionality


\textbf{dimension pienennys} dimension reduction


\textbf{Diracin deltafunktio} Dirac's delta function


\textbf{Diracin mitta} Dirac measure


\textbf{Dirichlet-jakauma} Dirichlet distribution


\textbf{Dirichlet-prosessi} Dirichlet process


\textbf{diskonttaus} discounting


\textbf{diskordanssi} discordance


\textbf{diskordantit parit} discordant pairs


\textbf{diskreetti} discrete


\textbf{diskreetti jakauma} discrete distribution


\textbf{diskreetti muuttuja} discrete variable


\textbf{diskreettiaikainen} discrete-time


\textbf{diskriminantti} discriminant


\textbf{divergenssi} divergence$_1$


\textbf{diversiteetti-indeksi} index of diversity


\textbf{do-laskenta} do-calculus


\textbf{do-operaattori} do-operator


\textbf{duaalilause} dual theorem


\textbf{duaalisuus} duality


\textbf{dynaaminen kiintiöinti} dynamic treatment allocation


\textbf{dynaaminen ohjelmointi} dynamic programming, dynamic optimization


\textbf{dynaaminen optimointi} dynamic optimization


\textbf{dynaaminen populaatio} dynamic population, open population
\lettrine[lines=3]{E}{}
% why use lettrine here???????????
\mbox{}\\\mbox{}\\\mbox{}


\medskip

 

 

 


\textbf{\textit{E}-optimaalisuus} $E$-optimality


%% \textbf{ECM-algoritmi} ECM-algo\-rithm


%% \textbf{ECME-algoritmi} ECME-algo\-rithm


\textbf{editointisääntö} edit rule


\textbf{edustava otos} representative sample


\textbf{edustavuus} representativeness


\textbf{ehdokasjakauma} candidate distribution, proposal distribution


\textbf{ehdollinen autoregressio} conditional autoregression


\textbf{ehdollinen jakauma} conditional distribution


\textbf{ehdollinen odotusarvo} conditional expectation


\textbf{ehdollinen riippumattomuus} con\-ditional independence


\textbf{ehdollinen tiheysfunktio} conditional density function


\textbf{ehdollinen todennäköisyys} conditional probability


\textbf{ehdollinen uskottavuus} conditional likelihood


\textbf{ehdollinen varianssi} conditional variance


\textbf{ehdollistettu sirontakuvio} conditioning plot, coplot


\textbf{ehdotusjakauma} proposal distribution, candidate distribution


\textbf{ehkäisykoe} prevention trial


\textbf{ei-merkitsevä} nonsignificant


\textbf{ei-negatiivisesti definiitti} nonnegative definite


\textbf{ei-normaalinen} non-normal


\textbf{ei-satunnaisesti puuttuva} missing not at random


\textbf{ekologinen harha} ecological fallacy, ecological bias


\textbf{ekologinen korrelaatio} ecological correlation


\textbf{ekologinen tutkimus} ecological study, aggregate-level study


\textbf{ekologinen virhepäätelmä} ecological fallacy


\textbf{ekonometria} econometrics


\textbf{ekonometrikko} econometrician


\textbf{eksakti testi} exact test


\textbf{eksogeeninen muuttuja} exogenous variable


\textbf{eksogeenisuus} exogeneity


\textbf{eksponentiaalinen kasvu} exponential growth


\textbf{eksponentiaalinen trendi} exponential trend


\textbf{eksponenttijakauma} exponential distribution


\textbf{eksponenttikäyrä} exponential curve


\textbf{eksponenttinen kasvu} exponential growth


\textbf{eksponenttinen silotus} exponential smoothing


\textbf{eksponenttinen tasoitus} exponential smoothing


\textbf{eksponenttinen trendi} exponential trend


\textbf{eksponenttiperhe} exponential family



\end{multicols}

\clearpage
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the right solution. `letterine` was there when I got the example file, I just cut most pages from it before posting it here.

Comment: Got more problems, but at least now I was able to make much smaller MWE.

Comment: @JoriMäntysalo  It would have been better to not edit the question and ask a new one if you get new problems, most people will not look at a question once it is flagged as answered. (You could still do that, revert the edit and ask as a new post, referencing this)

Comment: I will do that.